# Understanding this python code better

Tags: python, function

```
import urllib
from xml.etree.ElementTree import parse
candidates = ['4198', '4168']
daves_latitude = 41.98062

def distance(lat1, lat2):
    'Return distance in miles between two lats'
    return 69*abs(lat1 - lat2)

def monitor():
    u = urllib.urlopen('http://ctabustracker.com/bustime/map/getBusesForRoute.jsp?route=22')
    doc = parse(u)
    for bus in doc.findall('bus'):
        busid = bus.findtext('id')
        if busid in candidates:
            lat = float(bus.findtext('lat'))
            dis = distance(lat, daves_latitude)
            print busid, dis, 'miles'

    print '-'*10

import time
while True:
    monitor()
    time.sleep(60)
```

I did this exercise based on a real life problem. Dave forgets his case in the bus, and he wants to find out wich one of the canditate buses is carrying the lost case. I understand the code, but I can't find out the relationship between the first function and the second one, as

`def distance(lat1, lat2):
        'Return distance in miles between two lats'
        return 69*abs(lat1 - lat2)`

I understand what monitor() does but not the relationship between distance() and monitor() and how they interact to show the results, can you please enlighten me ? I am a n00b.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each degree of latitude is approximately [69 miles](http://geography.about.com/library/faq/blqzdistancedegree.htm) (111 kilometers) apart. So, `lat1` is a latitude of bus and the second `lat2` is a Daves latitude. By requesting this url in `monitor` you got latitude of bus, and then, using `distance` function, you got the distance in miles.

Comment: Ok, got it now. Things I don't understand yet : what is "abs" ? and why when we create distance() we assign parameters lat1 and lat2 ? Wouldn't it be the same writing lat and daves_latitude instead ?

Comment: Yes, you are right about second parameter - in this case it's always same value. For such a basic function as "abs" I would recommend using built-in help function before asking any questions - just type «help('abs')» in python console

Answer (score 0):

[abs()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#abs) is the absolute value of a number.

^ little link there for python 3 works the same for python 2.

if your looking for the meaning of [absolute value](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w-5R2Cze-Wc) <- that link there shows you a video.